# Remove consecutive identical elements in scala

Tags: scala

I have a list which may contain certain consecutive identical elements.I want to replace many consecutive identical elements with one. How to do it in scala

Lets say my list is

```
List(5, 7, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2)
```

I want output list as

```
List(5, 7, 2, 3, 5, 3, 2)
```

Answer (score 8):

It can be done pretty cleanly using `sliding`:

```
myList.head :: myList.sliding(2).collect { case Seq(a,b) if a != b => b }.toList
```

It looks at all the pairs, and for every non-matching pair `(a,b)`, it gives you back `b`.  But then it has to stick the original `a` on the front of the list.

Comment: OOOH! pretty.  I'm still a little lost on why it doesn't give back duplicates when you have a list like `List(1,1,1,1,1,1)`

Comment: Because the collect part never returns anything in that case. I was going down this path, but was pulling out the a instead of the b...which resulted in having to reverse to get the 2 out....had it backwards from a prettiness perspective. +1 for most concise

Comment: ohhh I get it.  `List(1,2,3,4).sliding(2) //>List((1,2), (2,3), (3,4)), NOT List((1,2), (3,4))`.

So `collect` is roughly `map[U]=>Option[Result]` and `filter(_.isDefined)`?

Comment: Downvoted because this obviously fails on empty lists!

Answer (score 4):

#### One way is this.

I'm sure there is a better way.

```
list.tail.foldLeft(List[Int](list.head))((prev, next) => {
  if (prev.last != next) prev +: next
  else prev
})
```

`foldLeft` takes a parameter (in the first application) and goes from left to right through your list, applying `prev` and `next` to the two parameter function it is given, where `prev` is the result of the function so far and `next` is the next element in your list.

#### another way:

```
list.zipWithIndex.filter(l => (l._2 == 0) || (l._1 != list(l._2-1))).map(_._1)
```

In general, `list.zip(otherList)` returns a list of tuples of corresponding elements.  For example `List(1,2,3).zip(List(4,5,6))` will result in `List((1,4), (2,5), (3,6))`.  `zipWithIndex` is a specific function which attaches each list element with its index, resulting in a list where each element is of the form `(original_list_element, index)`.

`list.filter(function_returning_boolean)` returns a list with only the elements that returned `true` for `function_returning_boolean`.  The function I gave simply checks if this element is equal to the previous in the original list (or the index is 0).

The last part, `.map(_._1)` just removes the indices.

Comment: The second one looks like a high-tech to me... Can you explain it too? :-)

Comment: @dexjq23 there you go.  I'm a little sleepy, so I may not be totally coherent.  Hope you learn something :D

Comment: Better (more efficient) as `if (prev.tail != next) next::prev` then reverse the result of the `foldLeft`. Also a check for `list.isEmpty` before you start, or it will throw an exception

Comment: Downvoted because both solutions are super inefficient — quadratic instead of linear!

Answer (score 3):

```scala
val myList = List(5, 7, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2)

myList.foldRight[List[Int]](Nil) { case (x, xs) =>
  if (xs.isEmpty || xs.head != x) x :: xs else xs }

// res: List[Int] = List(5, 7, 2, 3, 5, 3, 2)
```

Comment: I love how there are so many elegant ways to do the same thing in scala.

Answer (score 2):

**(answer moved from [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51932426/removal-of-consecutive-duplicates-in-a-list-and-retaining-element-order-scala))**

Here is a variant that is

- tail-recursive
- does not use any methods from the library (for better or worse)

Code:

```
def compress[A](xs: List[A]): List[A] = {
  @annotation.tailrec 
  def rec(rest: List[A], stack: List[A]): List[A] = {
    (rest, stack) match {
      case (Nil, s) => s
      case (h :: t, Nil) => rec(t, List(h))
      case (h :: t, a :: b) => 
        if (h == a) rec(t, stack) 
        else rec(t, h :: stack)
    }
  }
  rec(xs, Nil).reverse
}
```

Example

```
println(compress(List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a, 'b, 'c, 'c, 'a, 'a, 'd, 'e, 'e, 'e, 'e)))
```

produces the following output:

```
List('a, 'b, 'c, 'a, 'd, 'e)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val l = List(5, 7,2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2)

def f(l: List[Int]): List[Int] = l match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case x :: y :: tail if x == y => f(y::tail)
  case x :: tail => x :: f(tail)
}

println(f(l)) //List(5, 7, 2, 3, 5, 3, 2)
```

Of course you can make it tail recursive

Answer (score 1):

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
object HelloWorld {

  def main(args:Array[String]) {
  val lst=List(5, 7, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2)
  val lstBf=ListBuffer[Int](lst.head)
  for(i<-0 to lst.length-2){
    if(lst(i)!=lst(i+1)){
      lstBf+=lst(i+1)

  }

  }
  println(lstBf.toList)
}

}
```

Comment: Procedural, but easy to understand - nice when you need the performance. I would probably use `List.newBuilder` instead of `ListBuffer`, though - and if performance is really needed, I would use while instead of `for` comprehension.

Comment: @Suma Yes you can customize your flavours as per your liking.cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
val y = list.sliding(2).toList

  val x =y.filter(x=> (x.head != x.tail.head)).map(_.head) :+ (y.reverse.filter(x=> x.head !=x.tail.head)).head.tail.head
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variant

```
val is = List(5, 7,2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2)
val ps = is.head::((is zip is.tail) collect { case (a,b) if a != b => b })
//> ps  : List[Int] = List(5, 7, 2, 3, 5, 3, 2)
```

(the `is zip is.tail` is doing something similar to `.sliding(2)`)

Comment: @LP_, indeed it does. Various ways of fixing it, but a simple isEmpty test is probably the easiest